# question about abelian group

Tags: group-theory

Please someone can help me in this question?

Let G be an abelian group. Prove that every subgroup of G is normal.

I am looking for hints so that I can create my own solution.
THANK YOU ALL!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** For any $g,h \in G$, $ghg^{-1}=h$.